# find total distinct paths in a graph with given constraints

Tags: algorithm, graph

You are given a graph with k+1 nodes with one of the node marked as origin and a number N which is the required path length.

Assume all the nodes at unit distance from each other.

Find the number of different distinct paths possible when you have to start from origin and return to origin at the end of the journey.

you may visit any of the k+1 nodes as many times as you wish satisfying the condition that ending must happen at origin.

write an algorithm for the problem .with k and N as 2 inputs.

Comment: Do you want coffee with that?

Comment: the problem can be converted into a non-graph one by assuming we have K+1 distinct integers and we have to arrange them in a row such that no two numbers are consecutive and the sequence should start and end at the one unique integer. total length of sequence being N+1

Comment: @alestanis : sure .. I'm trying to solve this for last 4 hours ...

Comment: When you post a question here you should show some kind of effort on your side, or nobody will help you

Comment: @alestanis.  sorry,I should have added more details but I  was busy working out the solution ... posted a possible way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got it simplified to a series problem.

assume M = 4 and K = 2. { M is the total path length }

so we can have adjacency matrix as

[image]

total number of paths of length 2 starting and ending from A[0][0] will be the top left element of the square of this matrix. which is

[image]

so by raising it to power N we will get the answer . by some trying this is the formula I am getting

[image]

Comment: with further simplification it comes down to just finding k raised to the power m-1

Comment: What you are doing there is calculating the kth power of the adjacency matrix, which will give you for each cell (i,j) the number of distinct paths of length k from vertex i to vertex j, which as you said will give you the answer to your question. I don't understand the last paragraph; what is m?